# Double page headings with fancyhdr and fancyplain style in TOC/bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr

I noticed the bibliography and TOC, list of figures etc have the "section title" twice on each header, on the left and the right -- I have defined in the main body just the right part of the header containing the current section name (or chapter name if there is not yet a section name). How can I make this consistent among the remainder of the document, i.e. rather than bibliography at the left and right, just at the right?

MWE (shows the problem with bibliography, but it also exists with the toc and list of figures/tables parts)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@misc{test,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test1,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test2,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test3,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test4,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test5,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test6,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test7,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test8,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test9,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test10,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test11,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test12,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test13,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test14,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test15,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test16,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test17,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test18,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test19,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test20,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test21,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test22,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test23,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test24,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
@misc{test25,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\nocite{*}
\doublespacing
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion but I am not sure if I understand what the desired result is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% before redefining \chaptermark
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}%
}
\lhead{}
\rhead{\rightmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
%\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- removed
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\Blindtext
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

But start of contents is still without header

[image]

---

Or with package `scrlayer-scrpage`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark,autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\Blindtext
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first one was on the right track. `\rhead{\rightmark}` makes the heading mark appear to the right even when its a page with no headers (e.g. at the start of contents), however `\lhead{}` alone did what I needed.

Comment: In my example there is no header at the start of contents. Note that I have removed `\pagestyle{fancyplain}`.